# Пакет dbfpy, записи помеченные на удаление, как узнать?

Tags: python, база-данных

Возможно ли определить, используя dbfpy, в dbf файле помеченные на удаление записи?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`deleted` (атрибут записи) либо False (наглая ложь), либо True (святая истина)

Comment: Спасибо, не нашел в документации, да и сразу не понял ответ, т.к. нет автодополнения кода. Немного повозившись в коде, получил что-такое
[code=python]
dbp = dbf.Dbf("P110919.DBF")
for i in range(begin,end):
  if not dbp[i].deleted:
    pass
    #что-то делаем
[\code]

Comment: ну там в примере было что-то`db = dbf.Dbf(..); for rb in db:`, где rb -- строка (запись). А кроме автодополнения функцию dir() вроде никто не отменял...